# Horizontal curly braces inside matrix

Tags: symbols, matrices, braces

I'm trying to make this determinant:

[image]

But I don't know how to put the curly braces. I've tried with `\underbrace` but I get the brace only under a_m, not the entire space.

My try:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R(f,g)=\begin{vmatrix}
    a_0 & & & & b_0 &  &  &  \\
    a_1 & a_0 & & & b_1 & b_0 &  &  \\
    a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & & b_2 & b_1 & b_0 &  \\
     & \cdots & & &  & \cdots &  &  \\
     & & & a_m &  &  &  & b_n \\
\end{vmatrix}   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here there is my idea: to have the curly braces inside the matrix of your determinant I have used always `underbrace` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
R(f,g)=
\begin{vmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
a_0 &   &   &   \\
a_1 & a_0 &  &  \\
a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & \\
 & \ldots &  &  \\
 &   &   & a_m 
\end{matrix}}_{n \text{ columns}} & \underbrace{\begin{matrix}
b_0 &   &   &   \\
b_1 & b_0 &  &  \\
b_2 & b_1 & b_0 & \\
 & \ldots &  &  \\
 &   &   & b_m 
\end{matrix}}_{m \text{ columns}}\\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This MWE have the curly brackets more inside:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
R(f,g)=\begin{array}{c}
\begin{vmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
a_0 &   &   &   \\
a_1 & a_0 &  &  \\
a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & \\
 & \ldots &  &  \\
 &   &   & a_m 
\end{matrix}}_{n \text{ columns}} & \underbrace{\begin{matrix}
b_0 &   &   &   \\
b_1 & b_0 &  &  \\
b_2 & b_1 & b_0 & \\
 & \ldots &  &  \\
 &   &   & b_m 
\end{matrix}}_{m \text{ columns}}\\
 & 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nicematrix`. Some work is needed to pull the braces nearer the matrix, but not so much: the idea is to use a phantom matrix to set the width for the underbrace; then it is raised up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text to show spacing around the display

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
R(f,g)=
\begin{vNiceMatrix}[last-row]
  a_0 & & & & b_0 &  &  &  \\
  a_1 & a_0 & & & b_1 & b_0 &  &  \\
  a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & & b_2 & b_1 & b_0 &  \\
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cdots} & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cdots}  &  \\
  & & & a_m &  &  &  & b_n \\
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{%
    \raisebox{1ex}{$
      \underbrace{%
        \hphantom{\begin{matrix} a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_m\end{matrix}}
      }_{\text{$n$ columns}}
    $}%
  }
  &
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{%
    \raisebox{1ex}{$
      \underbrace{%
        \hphantom{\begin{matrix} b_0 & b_1 & b_2 & b_n\end{matrix}}
      }_{\text{$m$ columns}}
    $}%
  }
\end{vNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note the `\multicolumn` instructions in the body to avoid misalignments.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would place the two underbraced explanatory expressions *outside* the vertical bars. This may be done by with the help of 2 "`\smash`ed" `matrix` environments and two judiciously chosen typographic struts -- one inside the `\left\vert ... \right\vert` group, containing a matrix with 5 columns, and one outside that group, containing a matrix with 7 columns (and a `\smash[t]` directive).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
R(f,g)=
\left\vert 
  \smash{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
    a_0 &     &     &    \\
    a_1 & a_0 &     &   \\
    a_2 & a_1 & a_0 &   \\
        & \cdots   \\
     & & & a_m  
     \end{matrix}}_{\text{$n$ columns}}}\;
  \smash{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
    b_0 &     &     &    \\
    b_1 & b_0 &     &   \\
    b_2 & b_1 & b_0 &   \\
        & \cdots   \\
     & & & b_n  
     \end{matrix}}_{\text{$m$ columns}}}
  %% insert a first typographic strut:
  \vphantom{\begin{matrix} 1\\2\\3\\4\\5 \end{matrix}}
\right\vert
%% insert a second typographic strut:
\smash[t]{\vphantom{\begin{matrix} 1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7 \end{matrix}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the colours of the your code. All the characters have the same gray color.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Not sure if the absence of color is a problem, but it *is* deliberate; see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8668/5001 for more information.

Comment: In my humble opinion there are many things still to be fixed on TeX.SE.